# Plot number of occurrences from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns. One of them is containing timestamps and another one - id of some action. Something like that:

```
2000-12-29 00:10:00     action1
2000-12-29 00:20:00     action2
2000-12-29 00:30:00     action2
2000-12-29 00:40:00     action1
2000-12-29 00:50:00     action1
...
2000-12-31 00:10:00     action1
2000-12-31 00:20:00     action2
2000-12-31 00:30:00     action2
```

I would like to know how many actions of certain type have been performed in a certain day.
I.e. for every day, I need to count the number of occurrences of actionX and plot this data with date on X axis and number of occurrences of actionX on Y axes, for each date.

Of course I can count actions for each day naively just by iterating through my dataset. But what's the "right way" to do in with pandas/matplotlib?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from

```
                mydate col_name
0  2000-12-29 00:10:00  action1
1  2000-12-29 00:20:00  action2
2  2000-12-29 00:30:00  action2
3  2000-12-29 00:40:00  action1
4  2000-12-29 00:50:00  action1
5  2000-12-31 00:10:00  action1
6  2000-12-31 00:20:00  action2
7  2000-12-31 00:30:00  action2
```

You can do

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'])
df = df.set_index('mydate')
df['day'] = df.index.date
counts = df.groupby(['day', 'col_name']).agg(len)
```

but perhaps there's an even more straightforward way. the above should work anyway.

If you want to use counts as a DataFrame, I'd then transform it back

```
counts = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns=['count'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed the last line in your code like this: `counts = df.groupby([df.day.to_period('D'), 'col_name']).agg(len)`, as I need to group data by day and not by exact time from the index. It worked and gave me multiindexed Series object. However I still cannot plot this data as I cannot `unstack` them. I asked separate question on this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352520/pandas-unstack-doesnt-work
and it seems that there's a bug.

But as `unstack` doesn't work, maybe there's another way to plot this data? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

You can get the counts by using

```
df.groupby([df.index.date, 'action']).count()
```

or you can plot directly using this method

```
df.groupby([df.index.date, 'action']).count().plot(kind='bar')
```

You could also just store the results to `count` and then plot it separately. This is assuming that your index is already in datetimeindex format, otherwise follow the directions of @mkln above.

Comment: It is ofter usefull to get the results in order, so I'd add `order()` to the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I find the combo `.count_values().plot.bar()` very intuitive to do histogram plot. It also puts categories in the right order for you and, in many cases where there are too many categories, you can simply do `.count_values().iloc[:k].plot.bar()`.

So, what I would do in your case is to compute a new Pandas Series of date+action, formatted for readability, and then invoke one of the snippet above. The code might look like this:

```
date_and_action = df['date'].astype(str).str.slice(0, 10) + '_' + df['action']
date_and_action.count_values().iloc[:k].plot.bar()
```