# Pandas unstack doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

Initially I had DF with 1 column of actions indexed with DatetimeIndex:

```
In [371]: dates
2013-12-29 19:21:00    action1
2013-12-29 19:21:01    action2
2013-12-29 19:21:11    action1
2013-12-29 19:21:13    action2
                           ...
In [372]: dates.index
    Out[372]: 
    <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
    [2013-12-29 19:02:27, ..., 2014-01-13 16:30:31]
    Length: 108957, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I want to plot number of actions of certain type vs day

So I grouped actions by date, using `agg`

```
grouped = dates.groupby([dates.index.to_period(freq = 'D'), 'actiontype']).agg(len)
```

Which gave me multiindexed series:

```
...
2014-01-13  action1       435
            action2       2067
..
2014-01-14  action1       455
            action2       1007
...
```

Which seems to be precisely what I need.

But when tried `unstack` the series to get rid of the MultiIndex and plot my data, and got the error:

```
In [379]: grouped.unstack()

ValueError: freq not specified and cannot be inferred from first element
```

What's my mistake here? Thank you.

Comment: I notice there's an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4342) with this error. Is that related to what you see here?

Comment: @chrisaycock I've seen this page, but I'm not sure it's exactly my case. I'm very new in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use `.unstack()` and it doesn't work with that multiindex, then starting from the non-indexed data

```
index                 mydate     action
    0    2000-12-29 00:10:00    action1
    1    2000-12-29 00:20:00    action2
    2    2000-12-29 00:30:00    action2
    3    2000-12-29 00:40:00    action1
    4    2000-12-29 00:50:00    action1
    5    2000-12-31 00:10:00    action1
    6    2000-12-31 00:20:00    action2
    7    2000-12-31 00:30:00    action2
```

you could do something like

```
df['day'] = df['mydate'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
counts = df.groupby(['day', 'action']).agg(len)
```

basically you forget about the datetime being a datetime, you just keep it as a string and you only keep the date, discarding the time. now pandas will be dumb on the time dimension but `counts.unstack()` gives you

```
             mydate         
action      action1  action2
day                         
2000-12-29        3        2
2000-12-31        1        2
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I haven't came actoss lambdas yet, so never through about this solution. It only needs slight modification - "mydate" should be converted into string data type in order to `split()` it. : `dates['day'] = dates['mydate'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split()[0])`