# Plot number of occurrences in Pandas dataframe (2)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, charts

this is a followup from the previous question: [Plot number of occurrences from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331722/plot-number-of-occurrences-from-pandas-dataframe)

I'm trying to produce a bar chart in descending order from the results of a pandas dataframe that is grouped by "Issuing Office." The data comes from a csv file which has 3 columns: System (string), Issuing Office (string), Error Type (string).  The first four commands work fine - read, fix the column headers, strip out the offices I don't need, and reset the index.  However I've never displayed a chart before.

CSV looks like:

```
System Issuing Office Error Type
East   N1             Error1
East   N1             Error1
East   N2             Error1
West   N1             Error3
```

Looking for a simple horizontal bar chart that would show N1 had a count of 3, N2 had a count of 2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mydatafile.csv',index_col=None, header=0)    #ok
df.columns = [c.replace(' ','_') for c in df.columns]          #ok
df = df[df['Issuing_Office'].str.contains("^(?:N|M|V|R)")]     #ok
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)                                 #ok

# produce chart that shows how many times an office came up (Decending)
df.groupby([df.index, 'Issuing_Office']).count().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

# produce chart that shows how many error types per Issuing Office (Descending).
```

There are no date fields in this which makes it different than the original question.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: maybe this is what you want? `df['issuing_office'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` I don't think you need to use groupby at all here, or if you do, probably didn't mean to include the index in it?  I mean, if you just remove "df.index" from "groupby" it's basically going to work, albeit with some extraneous stuff.

Answer (score 1):

JohnE's solution worked.  Used the code:

```
# produce chart that shows how many times an office came up (Decending)
df['Issuing_Office'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')   #--JohnE
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()

# produce chart that shows how many error types per Issuing Office N1 (Descending).
dfN1 = df[df['Issuing_Office'].str.contains('N1')]
dfN1['Error_Type'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```