# Plotting DataFrame with a datetime.time object problems

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I've started learning pandas for a few days now so that I can do a few analyzes of a big data set that I have received.

My goal is:

**1. To visualize the scan count per minute. (x=time, y=number of total scans)**

**2. To visualize the scans per minute on a graph. (x=time, y=number of scans that minute)**

If this is not clear enough let me know and I'll try my best to re-explain it.

I created a new DataFrame consisting of 2 columns: Scan Type and Time

```
$ df.head()

             Scan Type      Time
0  Mobile Multi Reject  13:32:00
1  Mobile Multi Reject  13:33:00
2  Mobile Multi Reject  13:33:00
3       Barcode Reject  13:34:00
4        Barcode Entry  13:34:00
```

The data types are as follows:

```
$ df.dtypes

Scan Type    object
Time         object
dtype: object
```

My next step was to convert the Time object to datetime:

```
$ df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

$ df.dtypes

Scan Type            object
Time         datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Then I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21333244/1067213  to present the data based on the count and got the following:

[image: Scan Types based on Time]

**Issue 1:** The time is presented wrong and I don't understand what it uses as the time. The graph seems correct since the expected peak moments and scan flow matches with the expected one (through experience).

**Issue 2:** I could not manage to present the total scans based on the time.

Thanks in advance, for more clarity or if you have any questions please leave a comment and I'll try my best to clarify or provide more information.

***EDIT: This exactly the code I used to visualize the data:***

```
data = pd.read_excel("Scanlog.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Scan Type', 'Time'])

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S", errors="coerce")
df.groupby([df['Time']]).count().plot(style=".", figsize=(15, 4))
```

**EDIT 2 - Solution for Issue 1:**
After some research I found that the missing part was the dt.time:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S", errors="coerce").dt.time
```

Now the time is presented properly.

Comment: Can you include the actual code you used to generate the plot please?

Comment: @ScottSkiles of course, I added it now!

Comment: You're using the built-in plot for pandas. It is using the index. If you set df.index = df["Time"] before you plot you should be good. On mobile so I can't test this.

Comment: @ScottSkiles it displays the same thing. I have just noticed it uses the dates 01-1-1900. Even though the date is never provided.